# bash shell reworking variable replace dots by underscore

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I can't see to get it working :

```
echo $VERSIONNUMBER
```

i get : v0.9.3-beta

```
VERSIONNUMBERNAME=${VERSIONNUMBER:1}
echo $VERSIONNUMBERNAME
```

I get : 0.9.3-beta

```
VERSION=${VERSIONNUMBERNAME/./_}
echo $VERSION
```

I get : 0_9.3-beta

I want to have  : 0_9_3-beta

I've been googling my brains out I can't make heads or tails of it.

Ideally I'd like to remove the v and replace the periods with underscores in one line.

Comment: Another good reference on the relevant syntax is http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: BTW, the title is (as originally written) a bit of a misnomer: these aren't regexes at all. bash's *regex* syntax is `[[ $foo =~ $bar ]]`, but it's not what you'd use for replacements.

Comment: ...if it *were* a regex, `.` would match *every character in your string*, as it's a wildcard in regex syntax.

Comment: Addressing just your "one line" requirement: bash doesn't support nesting multiple string manipulations (#1 and //./-/) in a single command. (You could use a semicolon between the two commands to make them fit on a single line though.)

Comment: this is baffling but okay o.O

Comment: What's so baffling about it? Do realize  that *one liners are not generally considered a good idea at all* -- trading away simplicity in exchange for terseness is the wrong direction to go if you're trying to build reliable code.

Comment: i'm so used to everything fitting into one line. something so trivial can't.

Comment: As above -- "fitting into one line" is optimizing for the wrong things. "Robust" software is software that handles unexpected edge-cases well; that has nothing to do with one-liners. (I wouldn't describe bash as a language that optimizes for writing robust software, except insofar as it does a better job of providing the necessary primitives than its predecessors such as baseline POSIX sh).

Comment: fair enough. thanks all!

Comment: `VERSION=$( echo ${VERSIONNUMBER:1} | tr '.' '_' )`

Comment: well waddaya know!

Comment: I'll make it an anwer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine pattern substitution with `tr`:

```
VERSION=$( echo ${VERSIONNUMBER:1} | tr '.' '_' )
```

Answer (score 12):

Let's create your variables:

```
$ VERSIONNUMBER=v0.9.3-beta
$ VERSIONNUMBERNAME=${VERSIONNUMBER:1}
```

This form only replaces the first occurrence of `.`:

```
$ echo "${VERSIONNUMBERNAME/./_}"
0_9.3-beta
```

To replace all occurrences of `.`, use:

```
$ echo "${VERSIONNUMBERNAME//./_}"
0_9_3-beta
```

Because this approach avoids the creation of pipelines and subshells and the use of external executables, this approach is efficient.  This approach is also unicode-safe.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> **Pattern substitution.**  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern
>   just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is expanded and the  longest
>   match  of  pattern       against  its  value  is  replaced  with 
>   string.  **If pattern begins with /, all matches of pattern are replaced
>   with string.**  **Normally only the first match is           replaced.**  If
>   pattern begins with #, it must match at the beginning of the expanded
>   value of parameter.  If pattern begins with %, it must match at the
>   end of              the  expanded  value  of  parameter.   If string
>   is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern
>   may be omitted.  If the nocasematch shell       option is enabled, the
>   match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic
>   characters.  If parameter is @ or *, the substitution operation is 
>   applied              to  each  positional  parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with @ or *, the substitution              operation is
>   applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.
>   (Emphasis added.)

Comment: that's already one step forward. why can't I do both operations in one line?

Comment: @tatsu, ...because the syntax isn't defined in a way that would let you? If you want to nest expansions, that's a language feature; if it's not there, it's not there.

Comment: really? I would think something such as `echo ${"${VERSIONNUMBER//./_}":1}` should do it. I'm pretty sure putting it into one line is doable

Comment: @tatsu, one *line*, certainly. One *parameter expansion*, absolutely not. PE syntax requires a variable name, and *only* a variable name, to be in the `parameter` position.

Comment: @tatsu, ...there are shells that allow that -- zsh is among them -- but bash is not.

Comment: that's wild. I though bash was robust?

Comment: @tatsu, `VERSIONNUMBER=v0.9.3-beta; VERSIONNUMBERNAME=${VERSIONNUMBER:1}` -- replace the newline with a semicolon,  and there you are, one line.

Comment: @tatsu If we were to start from scratch to design a shell language, it would probably have that feature.  For bash, however, the primary design goal has been to maintain backwards-compatibility with shell code dating back years and decades.  If you want the latest features, use `zsh`.  If you want compatibility with the untold thousands and thousands of shell scripts that are an integral part of your OS or are available on the internet, use `bash`.